# Issue running Github Maven Library on Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, github

I cloned [this](https://github.com/JoonasVali/NaturalMouseMotion) Github repository on my local directory, then imported via 'existing maven project'. I then proceeded to build the maven project as a package which was successful.

Based off the directions from the Github repository, I tried to run the following code, but could not. This is my first time touching java, but I'm really curious about this library and wanted to see it working. Does anyone have ideas as to how I can change my code to run this maven library?

```
package com.github.joonasvali.naturalmouse.api.MouseMotionFactory

public class Main {
    public static void main(string[] args) 
    {
        int xDest = 500;
        int yDest = 500;
    }
    public static void pleaseWork
    {
        MouseMotion motion = mouseMotionFactory.build(xDest, yDest);
    }
}
```

[You can see the library added on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pdcx.jpg)

Comment: So what errors did you get? Please add the full error message as text to the question itself.

Comment: I get a lot, like: The declared package "com.github.joonasvali.naturalmouse.api.MouseMotionFactory" does not match the expected package ""   Also, when I run my code, it starts to build the maven library... Really lost here. I would imagine there would be an easy method of uploading the library from github into eclipse so I could run custom mouse commands.

Comment: Please build the project (like using Maven and `clean verify`) and then report the error output by adding it to the question (not to the comments).

Comment: Furthermore: Is your own code inside the project or in another project? If it is in another project, have you set the dependency in the `pom.xml` correctly?